# how to prove universal introduction in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I am trying to find strategies to prove universally quantified assertions in Dafny. I see Dafny proves universal elimination
quite easily:

```
predicate P<X>(k:X)
 lemma unElim<X>(x:X)    
 ensures  (forall a:X  :: P(a)) ==> P(x)
 {  }
lemma elimHyp<H> () 
  ensures forall k:H :: P(k)
 lemma elimGoal<X> (x:X)
    ensures P(x)
  { elimHyp<X>(); }
```

but I can not find how to prove the introduction rule:

```
//lemma unInto<X>(x:X)    
// ensures  P(x) ==> (forall a:X :: P(a))
// this definition is wrong 

lemma introHyp<X> (x:X)
    ensures P(x)
lemma introGoal<H> () 
  ensures forall k:H :: P(k)
{ }
```

all ideas appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Universal introduction is done using Dafny's `forall` statement.

```
lemma introHyp<X>(x: X)
  ensures P(x)

lemma introGoal<H>() 
  ensures forall k: H :: P(k)
{
  forall k: H
    ensures P(k)
  {
    introHyp<H>(k);
  }
}
```

In general, it looks like this:

```
forall x: X | R(x)
  ensures P(x)
{
  // for x of type X and satisfying R(x), prove P(x) here
  // ...
}
```

So, inside the curly braces, you prove `P(x)` for one `x`. After the `forall` statement, you get to assume the universal quantifier

```
forall x: X :: R(x) ==> P(x)
```

If, like in my `introGoal` above, the body of the `forall` statement is exactly one lemma call and the postcondition of that lemma is what you what in the `ensures` clause of the `forall` statement, then you can omit the `ensures` clause of the `forall` statement and Dafny will infer it for you. Lemma `introGoal` then looks like this:

```
lemma introGoal<H>() 
  ensures forall k: H :: P(k)
{
  forall k: H {
    introHyp(k);
  }
}
```

There's a Dafny Power User note on [Automatic induction](http://leino.science/papers/krml269.html) that may be helpful, or at least gives some additional examples.

PS. A natural next question would be how to do existential elimination. You do it using Dafny's "assign such that" statement. Here is an example:

```
type X
predicate P(x: X)

lemma ExistentialElimination() returns (y: X)
  requires exists x :: P(x)
  ensures P(y)
{
  y :| P(y);
}
```

Some examples are found in this [Dafny Power User note](http://leino.science/papers/krml267.html). Some advanced technical information about the `:|` operators are found in [this paper](https://easychair.org/publications/paper/dM).

Comment: Slowly getting my head around this. But, not sure what the requires clause means in ExistentialElimination() as there are no parameters. I have assumed that a requires clause constrains the acceptable values passed to the method (lemma). Is their an implicit  notion of current  proof context that is being passed into the lemma?

Comment: A precondition usually mentions parameters, but whether or not it does, the rules are the same: the caller is responsible for proving that the precondition holds at the time of call, and the implementation (that is, the callee) is allowed to assume the precondition holds on entry. Dually, a postcondition usually mentions parameters and result values, but whether or not it does, the rules are the same: the implementation is responsible for proving that the condition holds on exit, and the caller is allowed to assume the condition holds upon return from the call.

Comment: A lemma is just like a method (except for some details that are not relevant here). For a lemma, the postcondition states the proof goal and the precondition states the antecedent under which the proof goal is to be established.